# Do I need a second NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, ios5, core-data

A function of my app uses core data to store expenses of user as an attribute. I'm trying to display the sum of all these expenses on the first section of my table view controller.

I've got it working perfectly when the sum is displayed at the section 1 of my table. However when I use the section 0 it just breaks. I've debugged the app to find out where and why it breaks. I figured out that the problem comes up when calling fetchedResultsController twice.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        if (section == 1) {
            return 1;       
        }
        if (section == 0){
            return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]; 
        }
        else return 0;
    }

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {

        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Gastos" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"nombre" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

The following code won't work because the _fetchedResultsController has been created for the sum, and will no pass the  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil).

Do I need to use another NSFetchedResultsController just for the sum? Whether it's the case, how would you do it? Thanks

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
            //id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        }   
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            static NSString *ct = @"CellSum";      
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ct];
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell;
        } else {
            static NSString *ci = @"Cell";      
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ci];
            [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath]; 
            return cell;       
        }

    }
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        //Gastos *g = (Gastos *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSNumber *sum = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
                         valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.precio"];
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [f setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
        [f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

        NSString *precio = [f stringFromNumber: sum];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:precio];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Suma Total:";
    } else{
        Gastos *g = (Gastos *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]];
        cell.textLabel.text = g.categoria.nombre;
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [f setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
        [f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

        NSString *precio = [f stringFromNumber: g.precio];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:precio];
    }

}
```

Comment: You posted `numberOfRowsInSection` twice, which is not necessary. You did not post your relevant part of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where the index path is {0,0}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the fetched results controller does not have any sections, so all rows are of section zero. You will have to modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to work in section 1 rather than 0.

You will have something like this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController 
   objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

In section 1 this will simply return nothing. Instead of `indexPath` in the above line use the expression

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]
```

and it should display your `fetchedObjects` in section 1.

As for the sum, you can simply generate it with the existing fetch:

```
NSNumber *sum = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
   valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.nombre"]
```

Comment: Mundi, your answer did the trick! thank you so much. I have updated my question above by adding the solution

Comment: your approach looks good for displaying the content. However if you go more in deep you get some problems. If an insert is made then the table will suffer a weird behaviour:
 case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     
The TV section 1 will display the first 5 fetchedresults. But if I restart the app, then data is correctly displayed. Delete and update works fine with a little it of coding, Any suggestion?

Comment: No weird behavior. You have to implement the NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods and also modify them accordingly (i.e. insert/delete the rows with the correct indexPaths).

Comment: please the updated code within mu previous comment. Anyhow Im close to the solution with your answer. Cheers