# Reload table after NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

This is the next question about my issue with NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert [asked before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652208/do-i-need-a-second-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

The following code is what I use in my NSFetchedResultsController delegate. Update and delete works just fine, excepts when I try to add a new Object to my model.

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:1]] atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:1]];            
            break;
```

My question is: How do I update the tableview after insertion? When I hit save, the new object is created. However the table doesn't update accordingly. I've tried everywhere with

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I've also tried to call perfomFetch within the ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

But table won't update until I restart the app. I've spent 4 hours looking for an answer but I've got stuck. any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to call `configureCell:` for an insert event, `[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...]` is sufficient. The table data source method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called to get the new cell.

Also, `indexPath == nil` for insert events, therefore your `configureCell:` call cannot work.

The important point is to call `[tableView beginUpdates]` in `controllerWillChangeContent:` and `[tableView endUpdates]` in `controllerDidChangeContent:`.

Comment: thnaks for your approach. I followed your guidelines removing configureCell: on the NSFetchedResultsController delegate. However this doesn't seem to help much with the new insertions. It remains with the same. It looks like fetchRequest fetches everything, but the TableView could not add new rows.

Comment: Do you add the objects on the same managed object context that the FRC uses? Or on a different context - in that case you need to merge the changes into the main context. Do other operations (changes, deletion) work correctly?

Comment: Yes everything works perfectly except the insert. And, yes I'm using the same context, I'm almost to give up :(

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
2012-07-26 23:19:43.093 CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source. with userInfo (null)

Comment: Perhaps you can post the code of your object insertion, and the code of the table view data source methods (numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Comment: Was there ever a final resolution to this? It's happening for me as well.

Comment: @WDyson: I have no idea. OP did not provide more information.